# Getting values from database in an item databound

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am looking for a solution for the following scenario I am using asp.net & sql server.

I have a repeater control ,I need to display an image within the repeater control , based on a range of 
values which are stored in a database table.

```
Database Table :
Level1 Min   Max
1      100   100
2      50     99
3      1      49
```

I used an itemdatabound event currently for the repeater control.
& hard coded the min and max values .
I would like to get the values from the database. 
One thing I could do is to write a stored procedure and call it within the item data bound event, but I am concerned it will effect the performance.

I would like to know if there is a good way to get the min and max values from the database without effecting the performance?

```
protected void rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

                int X = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "X"));
                int Y = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Y"));

                float percentage = (((float)X / (float)Y)) * 100;

                if (percentage == 0)
                {
                        ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("btnPerformanceImage")).ImageUrl = "../Images/Level1.png";
                }

                else if (percentage > 49 && percentage < 100 )
                {
                        ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("btnPerformanceImage")).ImageUrl = "../Images/Level2.png";
                }

                else if (percentage > 1 && percentage < 49)
                {
                        ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("btnPerformanceImage")).ImageUrl = "../Images/Level3.png";
                }
}
```

I am binding the repeater in code :

```
rptSummary.DataSource = GetSummaryInfo(BeginTime.ToString(), EndTime.ToString());
            rptSummary.DataBind();
```

The GetSummaryInfo method calls a stored procedure which performs a calculation an returns summary info x and y

Comment: How do you bind to the repeater? Is it a list of objects of a class? Can you post that class too?

Comment: hey Amitd ! thank you  I just updated my post. Can you look at it and let me know.

Comment: what does `GetSummaryInfo()` return ?

Comment: how are min and max values calculated? and what is wrong with the method? seems good to me. One thing you can do it calculate `Percentage` in the stored proc itself and return it in `GetSummaryInfo`

Comment: Getsummaryinfo returns x & y , I use percentage variable to do the following claculation percentage = x/y * 100. I would like to change the hard coded values that i have in the event handler 0,1,49,100 , and use values that I get from the database table I listed in my post

Comment: you can use `if` keyword too inside your stored procedure .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717(v=sql.90).aspx .. add another additional out variable `Percentage` like `x` and `y` in your SP and calculate percentage and return it from SP .. access it like  `Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Percentage")`

Comment: Yes. I am sorry. I dont think I put my question across to you clearly. I generally need to write another stored procedure to pull the Min & Max values from the table. But I was doubtful that calling a stored procedure within databound event would cause a performance hit . I wanted to know if there was any other way , I could get the min , max values from the database, store it in a place and use it within the databound function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29944/discussion-between-sqlsamurai-and-amitd)